# First image in Juicyslider don't fit to width page

Tags: javascript, image, responsive-design, slideshow

I work on my personnal website and I've a problem with the plugin Juicyslider. I work on it for 3 days but I can't find the solution ... I'm a beginner :/

So, I put images of the problem below.
I use Juicyslider to make gallery image of my work. Everything is ok but except one thing. The first image load don't fit to the page. BUT, after using the navigation (previous or after) and when I go back to the first image, this one fit to page ... First of all I thought that was a problem with `position:absolute`, `display:none` and `width:100%`, and after I thought that was a problem in JS with the order of functions. But everything I try don't work

HTML

```
<div class="description-project">
            <div id="myslider_project" class="juicyslider">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="img.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="img1.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="im2.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="nav prev"></div>
                <div class="nav next"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.juicyslider {
position: relative;
padding:0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

.juicyslider ul {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none outside none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.juicyslider li {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: none;       /* all hidden initially */
}

.juicyslider li:first-child {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
display: block; 
}

.juicyslider .nav {
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
padding: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 500;
background-image: url(../img/nav-40.png);

.juicyslider img.maxw {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
filter: inherit;     /* for ie8 to inherit parent opacity */
}

.juicyslider img.maxh {
width: auto;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
filter: inherit;     /* for ie8 to inherit parent opacity */
}
```

And the JS file
    (function($) {

```
$.fn.juicyslider = function(options) {

    var 
    settings = $.extend({
        // these are the defaults.
        mode: "cover", // "cover" or "contain"
        width: 'null', // set null to make the slider as wide/tall as the window,
        height: 'null', // otherwise set any other values in px or % unit
        mask: "none", // "raster", "square", "strip" or "none"
        bgcolor: "#000",
        autoplay: 0, // 0 for no autoplay, any other postive number for play interval in (ms)
        shuffle: false, // set true to shuffle the picture order
        show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 300}, // effect params refer to jQuery UI
        hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 300}, // try 'puff' or 'drop' for the effect arg
    }, options),               
    slides = this.find('li'),
    amount = slides.length,
    current = 0,
    theWindow = $(window),
    viewport = this;
    turnSlide = function(event) {
        var step = 1;
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            step = event.data.step;
        }
        if (settings.shuffle) 
            step = Math.floor(Math.random()*(amount - 1) + 1);

        $(slides[current]).hide(settings.hide);
        current = (((current + step) % amount) + amount) % amount;
        // must make displayable before detecting the dimension
        $(slides[current]).css({display: 'block', overflow: 'hidden'});
        resizeImg();
        $(slides[current]).css({display: 'none'});
        $(slides[current]).show(settings.show);
    },


    // set bg color
    this.css('background-color', settings.bgcolor);

    // set the next button
    this.find('.nav.next').click({step:1}, turnSlide);
    this.find('.nav.prev').click({step:-1}, turnSlide);

    // set autoplay interval 
    if (settings.autoplay > 0)
        setInterval(turnSlide, settings.autoplay);

    /*
     * handling bg images resize
     */
    function resizeImg() {

        // set width and height of the slider
        viewport.width(settings.width == null ? theWindow.width() : settings.width);
        viewport.height(settings.height == null ? theWindow.height() : settings.height);
        vieww = viewport.width();
        viewh = viewport.height();
        viewRatio = vieww / viewh;

        bgimg = $(slides[current]).find("img");      // the current visible image

        var doResize = function() {

            imgRatio = bgimg.width() / bgimg.height();

            if ((viewRatio < imgRatio && settings.mode == 'contain') || (viewRatio >= imgRatio &&     settings.mode == 'cover')) {

                bgimg.removeClass('maxh').addClass('maxw').css({
                    /* get new height after adjust above */
                    top: (viewh - vieww / imgRatio) / 2,
                    left: 0
                });
            } else {
                bgimg.removeClass('maxw').addClass('maxh').css({
                    /* get new width after adjust above */
                    top: 0,
                    left: (vieww - imgRatio * viewh) / 2
                });
            }
        };

        bgimg.get(0).complete ? doResize() : bgimg.load(doResize);
    }
    theWindow.resize(resizeImg).trigger('resize');
```

And to finish, here images : 
Before using navigation (the slider fit perfectly in the page but a part of the image is cropped because don't fit in the slider)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbbpb.jpg

After using navigation and go back to the first image (everything work ...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScXTE.jpg

So I think something happen during the navigation event which not happen during the loading of the slider (the resize function for example ...)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after few days I found a solution, not the perfect one but it works.
I just add `theWindow.load(resizeImg).trigger('resize');` at the end of JS file ...
The easier solution may be the best.

If you are any better solution, do not hesitate !